# Add image to database using WCF service

Tags: database, wcf, image, service

I'm trying to add an image to a table in my database but can't seem to do it when using the WCF service

The code below gives an error

```
    private CRMEntities _crm;
    private readonly Uri _uri = new Uri("http://localhost/CRMService.svc");

    //Adds a new image to database
    public bool AddImage(byte[] imagefile, int epid)
    {
        if (imagefile.Equals(null) || epid.Equals(null)) return false;
        _crm = new CRMEntities(_uri);
        var i = new Image { ImageFile = imagefile, EP_ID = epid };
        _crm.AddToImages(i);
        _crm.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

But if I change it to this it saves fine

```
        if (imagefile.Equals(null) || epid.Equals(null)) return false;
        var crm = new CRMData.CRMEntities(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMEntities"].ToString());
        var i = new CRMData.Image { ImageFile = imagefile, EP_ID = epid };
        crm.AddToImages(i);
        crm.SaveChanges();
        return true;
```

Edit

But it works with other classes.

Like

```
private CRMEntities _crm;
    private readonly Uri _uri = new Uri("http://localhost:1677/CRMService.svc");

    //METHODS

    //SAVE
    public bool AddEmailProblem(string description, DateTime datecreated, int clientid, string mailId)
    {
        if (description == null || clientid == 0 || mailId == null) return false;
        _crm = new CRMEntities(_uri);
        var objep = new EmailProblem
        {
            Description = description,
            DateCreated = datecreated,
            CLIENT_ID = clientid,
            Mail_ID = mailId
        };
        _crm.AddToEmailProblems(objep);
        _crm.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

Saves to the DB.

The connectionstring I'm using is -

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CRMEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CRM.csdl|res://*/CRM.ssdl|res://*/CRM.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=CRM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Server01;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="CRM" connectionString="Data Source= .\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=CRM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Server01" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: You might get a better response if you post the error details - the screenshot you've included is just a generic error dialog. It doesn't give us much to work with. The text of the error message would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited the whole answer...

```
private readonly Uri _uri = new Uri("http://localhost/CRMService.svc");
```

Is a service Uri and NOT a DB connection string!

Check the config file for the connectionString "CRMEntities"

and call you code:

```
 private readonly string _connectionString= "<your actual connection string>";

    //Adds a new image to database
    public bool AddImage(byte[] imagefile, int epid)
    {
        if (imagefile.Equals(null) || epid.Equals(null)) return false;
        _crm = new CRMEntities(_connectionString);
```

**You cannot simply replace the DB connection string with a Service Uri, that is not possible.**